# How can I get response with Python from YOUTUBE API

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-api

I want to get a video category from youtube video. I know a youtube id and I want to have the category. I have a youtube api.

I know how to do it with browser. For example,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ZCJgvabihQ8&key="+MY_YOUTUBE_API+"&part=snippet"
```

If I run this code in browser I will have a result. But I don't know how to get the same result with Python.

This is my attempt to find a solution.

```
import requests
import json
API_KEY = ''
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ZCJgvabihQ8&key=" + API_KEY+ "&part=snippet"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
```

But I have a error. <Response [200]>

How can I do this task with Python?

Comment: HTTP status code 200 is not an error. Its success.....

Comment: I recomend following the [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Response [200]>` is not an error. when you send a request you get a response object back.
response object contains response data. you can extact required data from response.
for example to get json data you can do.

```
print(r.json())
```

for more information checkout https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/